# PHP How to echo specific key in JSON object?

Tags: php, json

I have this JSON object:

```
 $json = '{
   "droplet":{
      "id":3286068,
      "name":"some.domain.com",
      "memory":512,
      "vcpus":1,
      "disk":20,
      "locked":false,
      "status":"active",
      "kernel":{
         "id":377,
         "name":"CentOS 6.5 x64 vmlinuz-2.6.32-431.1.2.0.1.el6.x86_64",
         "version":"2.6.32-431.1.2.0.1.el6.x86_64"
      },
      "created_at":"2014-11-25T19:54:41Z",
      "features":[
         "virtio"
      ],
      "backup_ids":[

      ],
      "next_backup_window":null,
      "snapshot_ids":[
         8724513
      ],
      "image":{
         "id":8385856,
         "name":"rr1.2",
         "distribution":"CentOS",
         "slug":null,
         "public":false,
         "regions":[
            "nyc2",
            "nyc2"
         ],
         "created_at":"2014-12-25T19:09:02Z",
         "min_disk_size":20
      },
      "size_slug":"512mb",
      "networks":{
         "v4":[
            {
               "ip_address":"104.131.211.202",
               "netmask":"255.255.224.0",
               "gateway":"104.131.192.1",
               "type":"public"
            }
         ],
         "v6":[

         ]
      },
      "region":{
         "name":"New York 2",
         "slug":"nyc2",
         "sizes":[

         ],
         "features":[
            "virtio",
            "private_networking",
            "backups"
         ],
         "available":null
      }
   }
}';
```

I can run this:

```
$arr = json_decode($json);

echo "{$arr->droplet->id}";
```

and echo out the id just fine. But I have been trying 2 hours to echo the ip_address that is deeper in the JSON object...

How do I echo the ip_address and nothing but the ip_address?

P.S. Please don't show me how to do this with a regex. I can do it that way. I want to learn how to echo "ip_address" in the same way I'm echo'ing the "id".

Comment: `var_dump($arr)` to see what the structure is. probably it's not decoding to an object, just a plain php array.

Comment: Giving that massive JSON in one line is not particularly helpful for people trying to read the structure.

Comment: tools like http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com can help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to look deeper into the JSON object. If you do this:

```
echo $arr->droplet->networks->v4[0]->ip_address;
```

It outputs:

```
104.131.211.202
```

As far as explaining the breakdown of JSON, consider that each "{" or "[" takes you deeper into the structure, while each "," is horizontal on the current level. This means that *id* is parallel with *networks*, and what we want is beneath *networks*, so we point into it instead. Following that same pattern inside of *networks*, we go down into *v4*, which is an array. Positions within an array are referenced through square brackets containing the index. Since we want the first position, we use *[0]*. Finally, *ip_address* is on our current level, so we can point to it here.

Comment: I was missing the "[0]" part of "v4[0]" completely. Thanks!